# application stop response when drag-and-drop file from file dialog

Tags: java, swing, dialog, swt

Hi, everyone.

I am writing a method in Java to open file dialog to let user choose files, 
I tried to use SWT because I want file dialog UI looks like system file dialog UI (In windows 7, JFileChooser's file dialog UI is quit different from the system file dialog UI).

It works fine until I drag file from file dialog, when I drag file into the application it stopped without any error message and never recover, after I tried many times, I noticed if I don't add JTextField into UI this problem would not happen, but stop using JTextField doesn't seems like a solution, is there anyone knows how to fix this?I am using swt-4.5-win32-win32-x86 and JDK1.8.0_91.This is the sample code about this problem:

```
    import java.awt.Dimension;
    import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
    import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
    import javax.swing.JButton;
    import javax.swing.JFrame;
    import javax.swing.JPanel;
    import javax.swing.JTextField;
    import javax.swing.UIManager;
    import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
    import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
    import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
    import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.FileDialog;
    import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;

    public class FileDialogExample extends JFrame {
        public FileDialogExample() {
            super();
            setSize(new Dimension(400, 130));
            setResizable(false);
        }

        public static void main(final String[] args){
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (InstantiationException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
                FileDialogExample controlFrame = new FileDialogExample();
                controlFrame.setTitle("FileDialogExample");
                controlFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                controlFrame.getContentPane().add(initUI());
                controlFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                controlFrame.setVisible(true);
        }

        public static JPanel initUI() {
            JPanel ret = new JPanel();

            JButton openFileDialog = new JButton("Open file");
            openFileDialog.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                    Display display = new Display ();
                    Shell shell = new Shell (display);
                    // Don't show the shell.
    //              shell.open ();  
                    FileDialog fd = new FileDialog(shell, SWT.OPEN);
                    fd.setText("Open");
                    fd.setFilterPath("C:/");
                    String selected = fd.open();
                    System.out.println(selected);
                    shell.close();
                    while (!shell.isDisposed ()) {
                        if (!display.readAndDispatch ()) display.sleep ();
                    }
                    display.dispose ();             
                }

            });
            ret.add(openFileDialog);

            JTextField textField = new JTextField("TextField");
            ret.add(textField); // Add textField into panel would cause drag in error. 
            return ret;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Mixing Swing and SWT like this is a bad idea. It is difficult to use them together like this without getting all sorts of problems. Stick to one or the other.

Comment: Actually before I used Swing + SWT, I was using only Swing and open file dialog with JNI but ran into the same problem. So I think mixing Swing and SWT is not the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use Text instead of JTextField. If you are using SWT then you should use all controls of SWT. Swing controls in SWT may throw exception, that might be the reason for appliction to hang.